# npm start & does not start the application, Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I ran into a problem. I want to first install the dependencies in the application when I start a Job and then run it. Here is my pipeline config jenkins:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }

        stage('Run') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm start &'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything builds without errors
[image]

But the application, unfortunately, does not start. Help me please, here are the logs:

```
Started by user admin
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/panic08/lapay-payment-frontendd
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /home/panic/.jenkins/workspace/Jenkins-testing
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /home/panic/.jenkins/workspace/Jenkins-testing/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/panic08/lapay-payment-frontendd # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/panic08/lapay-payment-frontendd
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.34.1'
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/panic08/lapay-payment-frontendd +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision f0c9cf9c6f5d1708492c44cd77f2bf3178ece211 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f f0c9cf9c6f5d1708492c44cd77f2bf3178ece211 # timeout=10
Commit message: "v4.0"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 975f62a81650b3e5a4e6f2b8c61ccc7f5423f214 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] sh
+ npm install
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@csstools/postcss-trigonometric-functions@1.0.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^14 || >=16' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@csstools/selector-specificity@2.2.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^14 || ^16 || >=18' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@testing-library/dom@9.2.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'eslint-config-react-app@7.0.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'less-loader@11.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 14.15.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'react-app-polyfill@3.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'react-dev-utils@12.0.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'react-scripts@5.0.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

up to date, audited 1514 packages in 14s

236 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run)
[Pipeline] sh
+ npm start
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

**Note**

If I don't start it with **npm start &**, but with **npm start**, then the application starts, but jenkins doesn't go to the next pipeline

Comment: _"with npm start, then the application starts, but jenkins doesn't go to the next pipeline"_ hmm which next pipeline? there is only one pipeline in your question and there isn't even a stage following the "run" stage. What is your **specific** question?

Comment: @hakre The question is that npm start & does not work. If I add a new pipeline, then it obviously won't pass because it hangs on npm start

Comment: If that is the question, the answer is, that it does work. And very much likely you intended to do something else - in both cases. What you still hide, but please share more, if you pretend to hide most parts of your question, its hard to answer.

Comment: @hakre I'm not hiding anything. It's just that after Jenkins runs "npm start &", it finishes, but the server doesn't start. If I run just "npm start" then I can't add the next pipeline because it just won't execute, jenkins will process it indefinitely.

Comment: Rest assured it does start, it's just that with & Jenkins does not wait until it finishes. without the ampersand Jenkins does wait until it finishes, but it does not finish on its own, so Jenkins continues to wait. You don't want both, but something different which I find not presented in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `npm start &` *does* start the application - but in the background.

As that is the sole thing to do - executing `npm start` in the background - the `sh` command does and then exits.

Jenkins realizes the "run" stage is done, cleans up and is happily done. As it was commanded to. The only person left alone is the user that meant to do something different, which is obviously not only hard to explain to Jenkins.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that Jenkins doesn't run the react server. It runs the "npm start &" command and finishes, but the server still won't start. However, if I ask it to run "npm start", it starts the server, it doesn't complete its work, but the server is running

Comment: Sure, because if you run in background, Jenkins cleans up when sh finishes - killing all child processes the stage created. In the other case, npm start is not in the background so it continues to run. Therefore the "run" stage is kept active by Jenkins as it did not finish yet. Where did you obtain the recipe to run a service in a stage script? This makes little sense for what you can now experience your own: It's either done before you got soemthing, or you get someting but can't do anything else in parallel. What are you trying to achieve with the running server?

Comment: I want to automatically deploy it after a successful build in Jenkins. To do this I want to run "npm start &"

Comment: Deploy? By running in the background? Then a stage in Jenkins is not appropriate for that. You could trigger some deployment action, but running in the background within a Jenkins stage does not bring you forward.

Comment: I want to unwrap the project if it builds successfully in jenkins. Like you said, I probably need to use something else

Comment: its a bit out of scope of the question, but what I'd normally do is to do this locally first, finding the right command sequence to do the work and then encode it as a jenkins pipeline stage. as every project is different, I can only guess that npm start starts the react app. check if there is a build step, like npm build and if not afterwards you find the files to deploy in the build subfolder or similar. check with the application framework you have in use how deployments work, this can be different.